# Stick header after scrolling

Tags: html, css

I made a header navigation and it's halfway down the page. When you scroll, and it's on the top of the page I want it to stick, if you know what I mean.

I hope someone can tell me how I get this done. [Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGz9w/)

**HTML**

```
<header>menu</header>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 2000px;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you cant do it just with css, i am not sure about media queries, but can be done with jquery though.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need some JavaScript.

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga6g3/2/)

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">AWESOME HEADER!</div>
    <div class="menu">Menu goes here - home - links - blah blah</div>
</header>
<div class="content">
    <!-- your stuff -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

.logo {
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#a00;
    font-style:italic;
}

.menu {
    background:#a00;
    color:#fff;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    width:100%;
}

.content { margin-top:10px; }

/* the trick */

.menu-padding { padding-top:40px; }

.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Javascript (JQuery)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
     var origOffsetY = menu.offsetTop;
     function scroll() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
             $('.menu').addClass('sticky');
             $('.content').addClass('menu-padding');
         } else {
             $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
             $('.content').removeClass('menu-padding');
         }
     }
     document.onscroll = scroll;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial. It explains how to do it using either CSS or jQuery depending on what you want.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/